# progress bar and ThreadAbortException

Tags: c#, multithreading, progress-bar

I have 2 forms. The main form with some code and the 2 form that has progress bar. While main form is working it became invisible and the second form as a thread apears:

```
 Thread pb = new Thread(Show_pb); //Show_pb shows the 2 form with green progress bar
 pb.Start();
 this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
 this.Visible = false;

 //do smth...

  pb.Abort();        
  this.Visible = true;
  this.ShowInTaskbar = true;
  this.Activate();
```

After all sometimes it throws an exception:

> Thread was being aborted

If I create `try..catch`in the `Show_pb` it will throw it everytime:

```
    try
    {
        Form2 f_pb = new Form2();
        f_pb.ShowDialog();
        f_pb.Activate();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
```

But I can't handle the exception that system throws. What should I change or how to handle this exception?

Comment: Never, ever call `Thread.Abort()`. Set a `ManualResetEvent` or something instead, and have the thread check it periodically to see if  it should exit.

Comment: Use a `BackgroudWorker` control.

Comment: @Irshad That by itself doesn't help if the OP uses the same mechanism to exit from the background worker thread.

Comment: @MatthewWatson Yes you're right. OP doesn't even want to interact with any threads if he uses 'BackgroudWorker'.

Comment: @Irshad A BackgroundWorker does use a thread, and the OP would still need to exit it at some point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the documentation on [ThreadAbortException Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadabortexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> When a call is made to the Abort method to destroy a thread, the
>   common language runtime throws a ThreadAbortException.
>   ThreadAbortException is a special exception that can be caught, but it
>   will automatically be raised again at the end of the catch block.

You can't effectively catch this exception.

The first thing is that you shouldn't ever call `Thread.Abort` **unless** your whole app is shutting down. It can also leave your app in an unknown state.

The next thing is that it seems that you are starting some UI in a non-UI thread. That's bad. You really shouldn't be doing that either.

The correct approach is to run your computation in a background thread and marshal the updates back to the UI to update your progress bar.